# Can not call API by domain name: CORS error

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, cors

My React.js website calls a Django REST Framework API.

The website is hosted by a hosting provider.

The API is hosted on a shared virtual server, it runs with NGINX. The address of the server is associated with a domain name that I own.

Everything works perfectly when the API is fetched with the IP address:
`fetch('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/userprofile', ...)`

But when I try to fetch using the domain name :
`fetch('http://www.example.com/userprofile', ...)`

...I get a CORS error:
`Access to fetch at 'http://www.example.com/userprofile/' from origin 'http://example.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

-> What should I change in Django or in NGINX to be able to fetch using the API's domain name rather than the IP address?

Comment: First google hit for 'django rest framework cors' was this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/ did you read it?

Comment: @Evert As I mentioned, my project works perfectly so yes, I have implemented CORS in my Django API, thank you for taking care of it. My issue now is to have it running when I use the domain name of the API instead of the IP address.

Comment: If you've implemented, you must have implemented it incorrectly. You might want share what you did to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

In the NGINX configuration file, the server name must be stated.

In my case, I had entered the IP address:

`listen 80; server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;`

To make NGINX work with the domain name, you have to replace the server's IP address with the domain name in this section :

`listen 80; server_name www.example.com;`

And then reload NGINX configuration file:

`sudo service nginx reload`